# WordPress custom page shows blog posts

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm working on a WordPress plugin where I need to create a simple custom page where I'll show my custom content. Everything is working great except one thing. In my custom page, after the footer that I added using `get_footer()`, some blog posts are been shown. I don't know from where this is getting added and how do I remove it from the page?

Please refer the below screen shot:
[image]

This is how I'm adding the page and rewrite_rule

```
function customop_custom_output() {
            add_rewrite_tag( '%print-projects%', '([^&]+)' );
            add_rewrite_rule('^print-projects/?','index.php?print-projects','top');
            flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'customop_custom_output' ));


function customop_display() {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/print-projects/'){
        include 'frontend-form.php';
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'customop_display' );
```

frontend-form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>My WordPress Plugin Front-end Page</title>
      <?php
         get_header();
         ?>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="row">
         <?php

            if(isset($_SESSION['guest-projects'])){
                echo '<h3>Print Saved Projects</h3>';
                    echo '<table clas="form-table">';
                    echo '<thead><tr><th>Preview</th><th>Name</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>';
                    echo '<tbody class="projects-link">';

                    foreach ($_SESSION['guest-projects'] as $r) {
                        $url = add_query_arg(
                            [
                                'action' => 'pn_delete_guest_product',
                                'pn_guest_product_id' => $r['pn_id'],
                                'nonce' => wp_create_nonce("pn_delete_guest_product")
                            ],
                            home_url()
                        );
                    echo sprintf('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>', '<img src="'. $this->get_pn_product_image($r['pn_id']) .'" />',
                    $r['name'], '<a class="pr-edit" href="' . $this->pn_edit_saved_project($r['pn_id']) . '">Edit</a> <a class="pr-delete" href='. esc_url($url) .'> Delete</a>');
                    }

                    echo '</tbody>';
                    echo '</table>';
            }else{
                echo '<h3>Print Saved Projects</h3>';
                echo '<h4>No projects saved!</h4>';
            }
         ?>
      </div>
      <?php
         //call the wp foooter
         get_footer();
         ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Could you please let me know how do I remove the posts from this page? Thanks!

Comment: can you show your `frontend-form.php` code?

Comment: @vel, I've updated the question with frontend-form.php code

Comment: seems it coming from footer.php

Comment: No. Removing it just removes the gray section (footer) from the page but not the posts section

Comment: can you share me the footer.php file? or share me site url?

Comment: footer.php is the default wordpress. I've not made any changes in that. Site is running on my local environment

Comment: which theme you are using?

Comment: Defualt "Storefront", woocommerce theme

Comment: 2 thoughts: (1) The `header.php` and `footer.php` which are included when you call `get_header()` and `get_footer()` usually also include the HTML to set up the top & tail of the page, so you'll be getting all that duplicated if you also include it in your own `frontend-form.php` and (2) are you sure that there's no post display widgets in any of the footer column widget areas?

Comment: @Peter, (1) If I remove the get_header() and get-footer(), then there's no header and footer on my custom page. But the posts section is still there. (2) I have not added any widgets, I'm not sure if wordpress is adding the widget on it own

Comment: You've misunderstood me - I'm not saying to remove `get_header()` & `get_footer()`, I'm saying to remove the duplication in *your own code* surrounding them. The lines from `<!DOCTYPE...` down to `<body>` (except for `get_header()` of course) and from `</body>` to `</html>` are already in header.php and footer.php so you don't need them.